# Side menu issue with toastbar

Tags: codenameone

I've a toastbar in a screen. When the sidemenu is opened as soon as toastbar appears, the sidemenu fluctuates a bit and don't work unless back btn is clicked. Normally the sidemenu closes if the screen is touched but it doesn't here.

Plz see the video here.

https://youtu.be/3zRN26FTij4

Update:

```
public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
    hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));
    hi.show();

    Command cmd = new Command("home");
    hi.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(cmd);

    Button btn = new Button("toastBtn");
    btn.addActionListener(e -> {
        ToastBar.showErrorMessage("this is an error");
    });
    hi.add(btn);
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this as a standalone test case?

Comment: See the update above. If the sidemenu is opened as soon as toast bar btn is clicked then the issue is seen. The issue is sometimes seen in the simulator as well

Comment: I was able to reproduce this but wasn't able to track the issue as it's non-trivial. Can you please file an issue with that test case and video. We'll try to address it

Comment: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2415